# Android app not opening on DeepLink request

Tags: android

I'm trying to open my app from a (example) link:

```xml
// AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.movieseat.app">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.movieseat.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:label="@@string/title_activity_main">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
              <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
              <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

As you can see the deep link should happen when I navigate to `http://www.example.com/gizmos`

I have my Pixel 5 connected through USB and I can find it in `adb`, and I run this command:

> adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/gizmos"

I've created a `.apk` of the project and installed that one my phone, but when I run the above command google chrome opens and loads the page `http://http://www.example.com/gizmos`

This is the output of the console when I run the `adb` command:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.example.com/... }
Status: ok
LaunchState: WARM
Activity: com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity
TotalTime: 220
WaitTime: 232
Complete
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the package name to the `adb` command fixed the  issue:

> adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/gizmos" com.movieseat.app